# Swift: Access to another ViewController's field

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to have a tabbed application, where one page is reserved for debug info.  So on that page, I have a text view.  I would like other view controllers and singleton (data access, etc) to be able to add to the text area.  I have tried the singleton pattern here, but I think that doesn't work because the singleton instance isn't the same as the "real" one that the application is using.  Is there a way to get access to the actual instance from another ViewController, or from other classes in the app?

Here is the DebugViewController:

```
class DebugViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var debugTextField: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    debugTextField.text = ""
}

func debug(text : String) {
    if debugTextField == nil {
        debugTextField = UITextView()
        debugTextField.text = ""
    }
    println("\(NSDate()) : \(text)")
    debugTextField.text = "\(NSDate()) : \(text) \n" + debugTextField.text
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A singleton will work but you can not bind it with IB. You need to create it programmatically in your AppDelegate.

Another idea is simply to place a reference to your `DebugViewController` inside those classes where you need it like

```
var sharedDebugViewController: DebugViewController!
```

and initialize them from you AppDelegate.

Comment: This would work, but I shouldn't be initializing a ViewController myself.  That (I think) was why my generic singleton didn't work - it wasn't the actual instance that the app was using. So all I need to make this work is the code to grab the actual instance.

Comment: If you want to use a singleton pattern then you have no other choice since IB  will create an instance via `init` and never via some `Class.sharedInstance`

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign a value to the other controllers UI like label , textfeild or any other by passing through a variables you can do it

you can do it with a global class so create as

```
 class GlobalVariables : NSObject {

    var variableOne : String = String()

}
var global = GlobalVariables()
```

now when you receive a message do it as `global.variableOne = your message`
 one you have set the variable to the global class you can access this variable in your application any where you want . 
on the other controller viewdidload 
 use as

```
debugTextView.text = global.variableOne
```

Comment: I don't actually want to navigate to the Debug Controller every time a message is sent to the text field.  I just want the messages to be there when I do navigate to it from the tab bar.

Comment: check wether now its fine ... it yes or no do tell

Comment: when you receive the message store it in global variable and assign global variable to that ui on viewdidload when you will navigate there any time it will be always there